# White rectangular background on Bootstrap glyphicon icons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having an annoying problem with Bootstrap glyphicon icons. The icon has white rectangular background around the image and it looks very ugly when used on top of colored backgrounds. Example of problem:

[image]

How exactly can I change this to be transparent with the red background?

Comment: Have you tried adding background: transparent to .glyphicon class?

Comment: Your question does not provide enough information for a useful answer. All I can say is it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/fjjsrw46/3/

Comment: Generally Bootstrap glyphicon icons comes up with the transparent background. For fixing your issue you have to share your html.

Answer (score 1):

This can be your existing css for `span` or `i`, `background`...If you are using `glyphicon` in span try this

```
span.glyphicon{
  background: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
tbody {
  background: yellow;
}
span {
  background: blue;
}
span.glyphicon {
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```